# how to know a dialog is closed in robotium?

Tags: android, progressdialog, robotium

I am doing a test project using **robotium**. I need to **pause** excecution of all the remaining **code** till the progress dialog is **closed**. Now i am hardcoding the time. But the problem is sometimes progress dialog will not close within that time period.*how can i do this?*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `waitForDialogToClose(long timeout)` method.

Hope this helps.